# WCF DTO versions

Tags: web-services, wcf

I have some services at the moment that return a dto with the following fields:

```
[DataMember]
public int Id { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

and I want to add more to this service by adding the following properties:

```
[DataMember]
public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

I'm not in a position where i can update the consumers of these services though - the client does that themselves.

My question is - will the old clients be able to just skip these new properties? and the new ones take advantage of them or will the serialization be an issue with the new properties?

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the old properties do not change (and the new one is marked as optional) you should be alright.

Said so, you should publish the new contract and get the clients to regenerate the service reference - or deploy the new version to a different endpoint so that when they're ready to switch they are forced to point to the new one.

Comment: It didn;t like it so i had to revert everything and then republish to a new endpoint - so i guess this is the correct answer :)

Comment: Thanks all for such a speedy response! :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen, the DataContractSerializer just puts null in for properties not found when deserializing. Makes tracking down some bugs quite tricky - sometimes I would prefer if it were more strict and gave an exception.

Another option to consider is subclassing the original DTO to create a new derived class.

In order for serialization to work properly, you need to specify the available derived classes for the supertype with an attribute:

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(DerivedDTO))]
public class OriginalDTO
```

In code where you use the additional property, you will need to cast the object to a DerivedDTO to get access to the property (I use the as keyword for this and check whether the resulting reference is null before using it)

Comment: I'm going to test this out - i'd rather not have different end points per release of the app.

:)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the new member `StartDate` is not declared a required field - so this would **not** work:

```
[DataMember(IsRequired="True")]
public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
```

But as long as you leave out the `IsRequired=True`, you should be fine.